# format cell with Long Integer in Table

Tags: java, vaadin

I've created a table where the data source is JPAContainer(connected on MySQL db).. And in table I have column with phone numbers. In Container type of phone numbers is Long Integer. I can see numbers in cells of column  bath with dot like thousands separator. On sample, if phone number is 2775 it appears like 2.775. How I can customize phone number and where do that(On JPAContainer or formatting column of Table). I wish out dot from view of phone number. Is there a way

```
table.formatProperty(columnName);
```

or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to format objects in a table is to either use converters or formatters as described in the [wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Formatting+data+in+Table) or the [book of vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.columnformatting).

[Formatting the Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) is then a small thing:

```
if (myValue == null)
{
  retVal= "";
}
else
{
  retVal= Integer.toString(myvalue);
}
```

Of course you should consider handling NULL values correctly.

Comment: is it the case for formatting? And for overriding method formatPropertyValue(Object rowId, Object colId,Property property)

Comment: You wish to display the value in a different representation, for this is formatting....

Comment: How I can formatting Integer? On simple, if we now for my problem above.

Comment: Edited answer to match the additional question